# How to apply ceiling or floor function on a decision variable

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

How I can linearize a constraint(s) with ceiling or floor functions via linear programming. I know I should introduce some integer variables, but not sure how and which constraints I should write to meet the desired purpose.

E.g., if the solver decides the value of the decision variable `x` = 4.2, then I want `y` (integer variable) to assume the value of 4

I am struggling with right formulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can model the expression `floor(x)` for a decision variable `x` by introducing new integer variable `y` (as you suggested) and adding the following constraints:

```
y <= x
y + 1 >= x + e
```

where `e` is epsilon : a small tolerance range

`ceil(x)` can be modelled in a similar way